# Youtube Data API and Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: javascript, python, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform, youtube-data-api

I'm having issues getting Google cloud endpoints working in tandem with the YouTube data API v3 in my javascript client. I think my issue is around the `gapi.client.setApiKey()` method setting the key for both my endpoints API and the YouTube api. When I do set the key YouTube works but my endpoints do not and I see the following error using my endpoints API:

```
{
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. The API () is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google
 Developers Console to update your configuration.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
}
```

Without the key my endpoints work but youtube search does not and I get this message using the search feature:

```
{
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
}
```

The code that loads the API is summarised below but essentially I have followed the endpoints python/javascript tutorial and the youtube data API tutorials!

```
init = function(apiRoot) {
  var apisToLoad;

  var callback = function(){
    if(--apisToLoad == 0){
      enableButtons();
    }
  }

  apisToLoad = 2; // must match number of calls to gapi.client.load()
  gapi.client.load('myAPIName', 'v1', callback, apiRoot);
  gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', onYouTubeApiLoad); 
};

// Called automatically when YouTube API interface is loaded (see line 9).
function onYouTubeApiLoad() {
    //sets the api key
    gapi.client.setApiKey('APIKeyForYouTubeFromDevConsole');
}
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more code here in what your handler does here? I know it can be done, and I know that using the same key for both your endpoints and youtube is wrong, but without more code it's hard to tell you what needs changing

Comment: Updated with some code, let me know if that helps... I think I need to specify which API I am setting the key for, but not sure how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify only the youtube API requests with the API key remove the `api.client.setApiKey` method call.

In calls to the YouTube data API add a key parameter to the API request:

```
var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
    part: 'snippet',
    type: 'video',
    maxResults: 12,
    q: searchValue,
    key: 'YourAPIKeyGoesHere'
});
```

This means only these API calls are authorised and not the endpoints calls.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not extremely familiar with the Youtube Data API. But I recognize the code you used for your Endpoints as the code that we provide. You can definitely use this code for the Endpoints API. For the Youtube Data one, I suggest [looking here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#create_a_playlist).

Looks like the code you need would be something like this :

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;

public class myClass {

    /**    
     * Define a global instance of a Youtube object, which will be used
     * to make YouTube Data API requests.
     */
    private static YouTube youtube;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube");

        try {
            // Authorize the request.
            Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "invideoprogramming");

            // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests.
            youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName([YOUR APP])
                .build();
        }
```

From there you should be able to use the youtube object to make your calls, and the gapi to send stuff to your endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the help = the link lead to something that gave me the answer, I'll post it as a new answer in a minute.